# Prove that if $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ are orthogonal then $\|\vec v+\vec w\|=\|\vec v\|+\|\vec w\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, inner-products, triangle-inequality

So if $\vec V$ is a real vector space equipped with an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, then using the [polar identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity), it is not hard to show that the equality
$$
\|\vec v+\vec w\|=\|\vec v\|+\|\vec w\|
$$
holds if and only if
$$
\langle\vec v,\vec w\rangle=\|\vec v\|\cdot\|\vec w\|
$$
and by the Cauchy-Schwarz theorem the last equality holds if and only the vectors $\vec v$ and $\vec w$
are linearly dependent. So if $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ are orthogonal we conclude that the first equality does not holds, that is
$$
\|\vec v+\vec w\|<\|\vec v\|+\|\vec w\|
$$
by the triangular inequality. However this it seems to me strange because the Pythagoras' theorem must hold  for any $n$ orthogonal vectors: indeed if the vectors $\hat e_i$ for $i=1,...,n$ are the vectors of the canonical basis then
$$
\|\hat e_1+...+\hat e_n\|=\sqrt n=\underbrace{1+...+1}_{\text{n times}}=\|\hat e_1\|+...+\|\hat e_n\|
$$
and clearly this holds for any orthonormal basis. So why my first argument is incorrect? and how to prove the statement? Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Oh yeah! $$\|\vec v+\vec w\|^2=(\vec v+\vec w\)\cdot(\vec v+\vec w\)=\vec v\cdot\vec v+2\vec v\cdot\vec w+\vec w\cdot\vec w=\vec v\cdot\vec v+\vec w\cdot\vec w=\|\vec v\|^2+\|\vec w\|^2$$ right? But if this is (surely) true, where the first argument fails?

Comment: So there should be squares? You should edit the question.

Comment: I think you took the square root both sides and distributed over the sum.

Comment: Indeed, there is an error : what you have to show is  $v \perp w \implies $|| \vec{v}+\vec{w}||^2=|| \vec{v}||^2+||vec{w}||^2$ with squares.

Comment: @chhro You said well. Forgive my confusion: I am tired and so I must stop to study today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that$$\sqrt n<\overbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}^{n\text{ times}}=n$$and that therefore$$\left\|\widehat{e_1}+\widehat{e_2}+\cdots+\widehat{e_n}\right\|<\left\|\widehat{e_1}\right\|+\left\|\widehat{e_2}\right\|+\cdots+\left\|\widehat{e_n}\right\|.$$

Comment: Oh yeah, my was a terrible mistake! Forgive my confusion: I am tired and so I must stop to study today.

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with your equivalent statements. If it were true: say $v=1$ and $w=-1$ which are linearly dependent.

Equivalently (?), $-1=\langle v,w\rangle =||v||\cdot ||w||=1$?

Equivalently (?), $0=||v+w||=||v||+||w||=2$?